# How to get all the variable from a list that has multiple lists inside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, return

now I have this `b` list:

```
[['AKRON', 65.5574], ['ALTON', 69.6722]]
```

it has two lists inside...
I want to get cities and numbers separately..
therefore I tried to use for loop to solve this problem:

```
def sortfunction(alpha):

    for city,number in alpha:
        city = '{:^30}'.format(city)
        number = '{:<5}'.format(number)
        return city,number
```

however, when I tried to print city and numbers, it only give me one value like :

```
('            AKRON             ', '65.5574')
```

but I really want are all variables from the list...is there any way can solve it?
PS: its ok to change b list to something else, I dont'mind...
Thank you very much

Comment: It would be better to use a  list of dictionary, [{city: 'Akron', 'value': 65}, {city: 'city2', 'value': 12}]

Comment: You are `return`ing on the first loop, so one `city, number` is returned.

Comment: OK, but how to change this kind of lists into dict? ....

Answer (score 1):

You're function returns the first items in the loop and don't find the opportunity to get to the other elements. Instead of return you can either use `yield` to return a generator or if you just want to show the result use `print`.

```
In [3]: b = [['AKRON', 65.5574], ['ALTON', 69.6722]]

In [4]: def sortfunction(alpha):
   ...:     for city,number in alpha:
   ...:         city = '{:^30}'.format(city)
   ...:         number = '{:<5}'.format(number)
   ...:         yield city,number
   ...:         

In [5]: for c, n in sortfunction(b):
   ...:     print((c, n))
   ...:     
('            AKRON             ', '65.5574')
('            ALTON             ', '69.6722')
```

Comment: I used print function, it did give me all the values, then I tried to format them.        a/b/c each includes  different cities and numbers                                                                                          (like: q = '[51-60]: {rainfall}'.format(rainfall = a)
            
    r ='[61-70]: {rainfall}'.format(rainfall = b)
          
    s ='[71-80]: {rainfall}'.format(rainfall = c)
            
  
   it just told me <generator object sortfunction at 0xb6c62504>...

Answer (score 1):

To get all the cities and numbers separately is a perfect use of `zip`:

```
def sortfunction(alpha):
    return list(zip(*alpha))

In []:
cities, numbers = sortfunction([['AKRON', 65.5574], ['ALTON', 69.6722]])
cities

Out[]:
('AKRON', 'ALTON')

In []:
numbers

Out[]:
(65.5574, 69.6722)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a easy fix actually you are returning the values, so instead of return statement just use print and it will print the city and number.

Due to your use of return the functions ends after first iteration.

Other Solution Use two list city and number and append city and number variables to these list and in the end return the city list and number list.